# Stop text scrolling with background using ScrollMagic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

I and trying to figure out how to stop the text from scrolling with the background image using ScrollMagic. But I have been unsuccessful. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/protonus/oapt12g6/). I have been trying for a couple of days but no luck. So basically I want the text to do what it would normally do if there was no ScrollMagic, it should scroll up when the user scrolls the page like it usually does if there was not animation on the background image. Maybe stoping the inner div from being animated?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  var galleryScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#gallery-main',
      triggerHook: 0
    })
    .setClassToggle('#gallery-main', 'slide-in')
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);

  var aboutScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#about-main',
      triggerHook: 0
    })
    .setClassToggle('#about-main', 'slide-in')
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);

  var productScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#product-main',
      triggerHook: 1
    })
    .setClassToggle('#product-main', 'slide-in')
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);

  var workshopScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#workshop-main',
      triggerHook: 1
    })
    .setClassToggle('#workshop-main', 'slide-in')
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);

  var blogScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#blog-main',
      triggerHook: 0
    })
    .setClassToggle('#blog-main', 'slide-in')
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);

  var contactScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#contact-main',
      triggerHook: 0
    })
    .setClassToggle('#contact-main', 'slide-in')
    .addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-background-colour {
  background-color: #EDEAE3;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.gallery {
  background: url('http://www.diong.co.uk/laurentino/wp-content/themes/laurentinoazavedo/assets/img/poppy.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 30%;
  -moz-background-size: 30%;
  -o-background-size: 30%;
  background-size: 30%;
  background-position: right;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transform: translateX(360px);
}

.gallery.slide-in {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.about-background-colour {
  background-color: #EFEDE6;
}

.about {
  background: url('http://www.diong.co.uk/laurentino/wp-content/themes/laurentinoazavedo/assets/img/orchid.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 30%;
  -moz-background-size: 30%;
  -o-background-size: 30%;
  background-size: 30%;
  background-position: 0%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transform: translateX(-250px);
}

.about.slide-in {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.product-background-colour {
  background-color: #F1EFE9;
}

.product {
  background: url('http://www.diong.co.uk/laurentino/wp-content/themes/laurentinoazavedo/assets/img/dalianew.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 31%;
  -moz-background-size: 31%;
  -o-background-size: 31%;
  background-size: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: 90%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transform: translateY(300px);
}

.product.slide-in {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.workshop-background-colour {
  background-color: #F3F1EC;
}

.workshop {
  background: url('http://www.diong.co.uk/laurentino/wp-content/themes/laurentinoazavedo/assets/img/iris.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 34%;
  -moz-background-size: 34%;
  -o-background-size: 34%;
  background-size: 34%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: 10%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transform: translateY(300px);
}

.workshop.slide-in {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.blog-background-colour {
  background-color: #F5F4F0;
}

.blog {
  background: url('http://www.diong.co.uk/laurentino/wp-content/themes/laurentinoazavedo/assets/img/tulip-red.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 28%;
  -moz-background-size: 28%;
  -o-background-size: 28%;
  background-size: 28%;
  background-position: right;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transform: translateX(260px);
}

.blog.slide-in {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.contact-background-colour {
  background-color: #F7F6F3;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.contact {
  background: url('http://www.diong.co.uk/laurentino/wp-content/themes/laurentinoazavedo/assets/img/flame-lillies.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 38%;
  -moz-background-size: 38%;
  -o-background-size: 38%;
  background-size: 38%;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: left;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transform: translateX(-300px);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.contact.slide-in {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/jquery.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
  <p>
    I'm a filler
  </p>
</div>
<a href="">
  <div class="gallery-background-colour">
    <section id="gallery-main" class="gallery">
      <div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>GALLERY</h2>
            <p class="larger-font">We create everlasting memories.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="about-background-colour">
    <section id="about-main" class="about ">
      <div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-4">
            <h2>ABOUT</h2>
            <p class="larger-font">Working with natural wonders to illustrate the clean lines of modern sophistication.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>

</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="product-background-colour">
    <section id="product-main" class="product">
      <div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>PRODUCT</h2>
            <p class="larger-font">Bla take on natural elements brings style to your space.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="workshop-background-colour">
    <section id="workshop-main" class="workshop">
      <div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-4">
            <h2>WORKSHOPS</h2>
            <p class="larger-font">We believe there is a designer in all of us.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="blog-background-colour">
    <section id="blog-main" class="blog">
      <div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>BLOG/NEWS</h2>
            <p class="larger-font">Our trends are ideal for the world traveller to follow.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="contact-background-colour">
    <section id="contact-main" class="contact">
      <div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-8">
            <h2>CONTACT</h2>
            <p class="larger-font">We are more than willing to meet and discuss your personalised needs.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to separate the animated background and your content. 
Right now, the text follows your background image because it is a child of the element you move.

I made your first slide (gallery) work with a little tweak to your code in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j8hv5ur1/ .  You can see that I animated only the background image instead of the whole wrapper.

```
<div class="gallery-background-colour">
    <section class="wrp">
      <span id="gallery-main" class="gallery"></span>
      <div class="container-fluid vertical-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>GALLERY</h2>
            <p class="larger-font">We create everlasting memories.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much @lordmarcoux. I have been trying to do something like this for 4 days already. I have moved the `overflow: hidden` to the **wrp** container as that seems to work for all of the sections.